# Why are javascript const array elements mutable

Tags: javascript

It seems rather counter-intuitive for arrays declared as const to have mutable elements. What is the reasoning behind this design decision? More over if one should need a truly immutable array in JS how would that be done?

Comment: `const` just makes the binding immutable, not the object assigned to it.

Comment: It wasn't so much "a decision" and more of a consequence of how arrays already work.

Comment: To make an object (which an array is) immutable, use `Object.freeze`: 
`const arr = [0, 1]; Object.freeze(arr); try { arr.push(2); } catch (error) {      console.error(error); }`

Answer (score 0):

Const is not meant to make your element immutable! it only ensures that your element stays the same so you cannot assign to it a different element!

Answer (score 0):

You can freeze the array with `Object.freeze`. This would make it so the elements cannot be changed.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

arr.push(4); // arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const frozenArr = Object.freeze(arr);     

frozenArr.push(5); // Error: Cannot add property
frozenArr.pop(); // Error: Cannot delete property
```

---

*Previous answer as it was, for reference*

A `const` array only prevents further assignments but you are allowed to change the contents of it.

The best practice for immutable arrays is to make copies, i.e. use `Array.slice()` with no arguments or `Array.from()`.

Example:

```
const originalArray = [1, 2, 3];

let firstNewArray = Array.from(originalArray);
firstNewArray.push(4);

let secondNewArray = originalArray.slice();
secondNewArray.push(5);

console.log(originalArray); // Output -> [1, 2, 3]
console.log(firstNewArray); // Output -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(secondNewArray); // Output -> [1, 2, 3, 5]

originalArray.push(9); // This is allowed
console.log(originalArray); // Output -> [1, 2, 3, 9]

originalArray = []; // Error: Assignment to constant variable
```

Comment: I see, I should be deliberate and code in such a way that strongly implies that an array should not be mutated, but I cannot prevent it completely. Also, regarding my first question, I understand that reassignments are not allowed: such is the nature of const. However, I don't understand the intention of allowing the elements to be changed. I guess my train of thought is if const is meant to make variables immutable why not make it completely immutable?

Comment: @eaglclaws Thinking about const made me realize I completely forgot `Object.freeze` exists, it might be what you're looking for. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

An array, number, string are all objects. They differ in the way they store values. A String are charcaters and therefore fixed if it has been declared const. An array is a construct of how multiple values are stored. This means that const sets the type imutable but not the values.

Comment: "*An array, number, string are all objects.*" of these only an array is an object. The strings and numbers (lowercase) are primitives. There are String and Number objects but they aren't immutable in that *the object* can be changed. The respective string or number value held not but that doesn't make the object itself immutable. The primitive values are *converted* to objects briefly in some cases but aren't objects themselves. And they are immutable by virtue of being primitives without any fields or anything.

Comment: To "change" a variable that holds a primitive you have to reassign the variable. Mutable objects assigned to a variable don't require reassignment to be changed. Immutable objects would

Comment: @VLAZ Ok. Thank you very much. I always learn something new. I actually asked myself the same question once and explained it to myself as I wrote it in my answer.